# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Japanese Language Stack Exchange](http://japanese.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Kanji question: the onyomi of 江 is found](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14335/kanji-question-the-onyomi-of-%e6%b1%9f-is-found)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [火の車 Where did it come from](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14546/%e7%81%ab%e3%81%ae%e8%bb%8a-where-did-it-come-from)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How do I say: I am on parental leave](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14372/how-do-i-say-i-am-on-parental-leave)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do you say "just curious" or "out of curiosity"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14388/how-do-you-say-just-curious-or-out-of-curiosity)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Relative clauses distinguishing whom/with which/that](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14541/relative-clauses-distinguishing-whom-with-which-that)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [using 〜ば〜ほど with adverbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14332/using-%e3%80%9c%e3%81%b0%e3%80%9c%e3%81%bb%e3%81%a9-with-adverbs)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [what does てやる mean when it is not used for giving?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14413/what-does-%e3%81%a6%e3%82%84%e3%82%8b-mean-when-it-is-not-used-for-giving)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Meaning of あります in the following sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14274/meaning-of-%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-in-the-following-sentences)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [how did 公 (こう） come to be derogatory](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14417/how-did-%e5%85%ac-%e3%81%93%e3%81%86%ef%bc%89-come-to-be-derogatory)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Using negative verb forms with はず](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14484/using-negative-verb-forms-with-%e3%81%af%e3%81%9a)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---